# Running multiple Task as async using WhenAll()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to run multiple Task using async but when execution reaches WhenAll() this method call never returns.

```
    List<Task> tasks = new();
    
    tasks.Add(Task.Run( async () => viewModel.Customers = await CustomerService.GetAllAsync()));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run( async () => viewModel.Orders = await OrderService.GetAllAsync()));
    
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

EDIT:

I was able to debug execution all the way into CircuitHost.cs, and on line 125 it stops there.

[image]

Here's the stack trace at line 125:

```
async CircuitHost.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<InitializeAsync>b__0()at C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Rider2022.1\resharper-host\SourcesCache\d848ab5bf79df2599514458b1cacef69f49ae55787993acba112f74d5315a7\CircuitHost.cs:line 125
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<<InitializeAsync>b__0>d>()
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<<InitializeAsync>b__0>d>()
CircuitHost.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<InitializeAsync>b__0()
RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<<InvokeAsync>b__9_0>d.MoveNext()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<<InvokeAsync>b__9_0>d>()
AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<<InvokeAsync>b__9_0>d>()
RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<InvokeAsync>b__9_0()
RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteSynchronously()
RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteSynchronouslyIfPossible()
RendererSynchronizationContext.InvokeAsync()
RendererSynchronizationContextDispatcher.InvokeAsync()
CircuitHost.InitializeAsync()at C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Rider2022.1\resharper-host\SourcesCache\d848ab5bf79df2599514458b1cacef69f49ae55787993acba112f74d5315a7\CircuitHost.cs:line 100
ComponentHub.<StartCircuit>d__13.MoveNext()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub.<StartCircuit>d__13>()
AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder<string>.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub.<StartCircuit>d__13>()
ComponentHub.StartCircuit()
[Lightweight Method Call]
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.<ExecuteMethod>d__23.MoveNext()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>.<ExecuteMethod>d__23>()
AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder<object>.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>.<ExecuteMethod>d__23>()
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.ExecuteMethod()
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.ExecuteHubMethod()
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.<<Invoke>g__ExecuteInvocation|18_0>d.MoveNext()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>.<<Invoke>g__ExecuteInvocation|18_0>d>()
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>.<<Invoke>g__ExecuteInvocation|18_0>d>()
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.<Invoke>g__ExecuteInvocation|18_0()
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>.<Invoke>d__18>()
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>.<Invoke>d__18>()
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.Invoke()
DefaultHubDispatcher<__Canon>.<>c.<ProcessInvocation>b__17_0()
ChannelBasedSemaphore.<RunTask>d__7<(DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>, HubMethodDescriptor, HubConnectionContext, HubMethodInvocationMessage)>.MoveNext()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.ChannelBasedSemaphore.<RunTask>d__7<(Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.HubMethodDescriptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HubMethodInvocationMessage)>>()
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.ChannelBasedSemaphore.<RunTask>d__7<(Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.HubMethodDescriptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HubMethodInvocationMessage)>>()
ChannelBasedSemaphore.RunTask<(Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.HubMethodDescriptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HubMethodInvocationMessage)>()
ChannelBasedSemaphore.RunAsync<(Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.HubMethodDescriptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HubMethodInvocationMessage)>()
DefaultHubDispatcher<ComponentHub>.ProcessInvocation()
DefaultHubDispatcher<__Canon>.DispatchMessageAsync()
HubConnectionHandler<ComponentHub>.<DispatchMessagesAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<HubConnectionHandler<ComponentHub>.<DispatchMessagesAsync>d__20>.ExecutionContextCallback()
ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop()
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<HubConnectionHandler<ComponentHub>.<DispatchMessagesAsync>d__20>.MoveNext()
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<HubConnectionHandler<ComponentHub>.<DispatchMessagesAsync>d__20>.ExecuteFromThreadPool()
ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
Thread.StartCallback()
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Comment: Do you mean that that task never completes?

Comment: yes, WhenAll() doesn't complete

Comment: what does the code up the call stack look like?

Comment: Could you include also the setter of the `viewModel.Customers` property, and the `CustomerService.GetAllAsync()` method? I assume that the Orders-related counterpart is similar. You could test this assumption by commenting out the Orders-related part, and see if the problem persists with a single task in the `tasks` list.

Comment: Could you try replacing the `Task.Run` with this custom `Run` method: `static async Task Run(Func<Task> action) => await action();`, and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It worked! Your last comment was the answer! But why does static make a difference?

Comment: Can you post your last comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to re-organize your code like this:

```
var customersRetrieval = CustomerService.GetAllAsync();
var ordersRetrieval = OrderService.GetAllAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(customersRetrieval, ordersRetrieval);

viewModel.Customers = await customersRetrieval;
viewModel.Orders = await ordersRetrieval;
```